# Unable to open debugger port (8600) Android Studio in MAC

Tags: android, usb-debugging

> Error running 'Android Debugger (8600)': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

This is the error I am getting while trying to attach the debugger. I have tried some of the possible solutions from Stack Overflow and Google nothing is worked for me.

Note: I am using Mac and Android Studio version is 3.4.1

[image]

Comment: Same issue. Nothing on SO helps. Tried restarting AS, invalidating caches, restarting machine, on vs off VPN, on vs offline, emulator vs physical, on vs off proxy... nothing...
Might be a Mac issue? Im on Android Studio 3.5.2